# Nebeans + Tomcat dying constantly

Tags: java, software-development

I'm using Netbeans 8.0.2 with Tomcat 8.0.15 on Raspbian and run some JSP-Projects on it.

The performance of Netbeans is not that great but mostly it does well... until everything crashes. 
I increased the RAM for Netbeans already:

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss4m -J-Xms64m -J-XX:PermSize=64m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true"
```

I know Netbeans can be quite resource-consuming but there must be a proper way to make it run without these issues...? Am I the only one to whom this happens...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Java 8 JVM (Oracle has the better(faster) implementation for ARM compared to openJDK. [download here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) : Linux ARM v6/v7 Hard Float ABI) so you don't need `-XX:PermSize` any longer. It was removed with Java 8 and your PermGem Space can no longer be full because it will use the HeapSpace.

Increase `-X64ms` to `-Xms128m` or even better `-Xms256m`. 64MB is not that much for an IDE like Netbeans. You can reduce the RAM used for the GPU to get more RAM for the CPU. Have a look [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt.md).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm using the Oracle Version already. PermSize is removed. I stacked up `-J-Xms128m` as there were some issues with `-Xms256m`. And in the config.txt I added `gpu_mem=32`. Let's see what will happen...

Comment: @Qohelet: I would like to know if you get any better with these settings.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me - after a week testing the system seems to be more stable. I will try to increase the value again, hopefully it works this time.